# Visual Studio Error: Type 'CoreApplicationView' and 'CoreWindow' Defined in assembly that is not referenced

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, uwp, visual-studio-2017, hololens

In Visual Studio 2017 I'm getting this error when I'm trying to compile:

'CoreApplicationView' and 'CoreWindow' 
The type is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'.
See the screenshots.

I want to deploy this app on my Hololens. I don't need the emulator.
I installed everything, also reinstalled several times. 
I followed these instructions:

```
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/install_the_tools
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/holograms_100
```

I figure someone with Visual Studio knowledge should be able to help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxMP1.jpg)[image]

Comment: What is the Unity version you are using?

Comment: Latest version 2017.2.0b8

Comment: What's your VS version? I also used Unity 2017.2.0b8 and my VS version is  15.3.2. I can build the project with no error.